# Generate <td> dynamic in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/42p561zn/

My problem is that I want to complete the row, with a ng-repeat, but no matter how hard I try, I can not get it to dynamically complete. I need this piece:

```
----------- I need use ng-repeat in this piece ng-repeat="usu in atypeUsers"
        <td >READ</td>
        <td >EDIT</td>
        <td >DELETE</td>
-------------------
```

I need to generate this with a ng-repeat, I must make it dynamic. My problems are not knowing where to put it. If I do it in a tr it goes down.
I must be not modify the structure of my json.

[image]

```
 $scope.aRoles=
     [
       {
         "type_content": "articles", 
         "type_usuario":{
          "administrator":
           {"write":true, "read":true, "delete":true},
          "other":
           {"write":true, "read":true, "delete":true}
         }     
       },
       {
         "type_content": "papers", 
         "type_usuario":{
          "administrator":
           {"write":true, "read":true, "delete":true},
          "other":
           {"write":true, "read":true, "delete":true}
         }     
       },
     ]        
    $scope.atypeUsers=Object.keys($scope.aRoles[0].type_usuario);


   <table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Type of content</th>
        <th colspan="{{atypeUsers.length * 3}}">
          Type of users
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td ng-repeat="usu in atypeUsers" colspan="3">
        {{usu}}
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

      ----------- I need use ng-repeat in this piece ng-repeat="usu in atypeUsers"
        <td >READ</td>
        <td >EDIT</td>
        <td >DELETE</td>
        -------------------
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="rol in aRoles">
       <td>{{rol.type_content}}</td>
       <td >true</td>
       <td >false</td>
       <td >true</td>
       <td >false</td>
       <td >true</td>
       <td >false</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

i need this

[image]

Comment: how do you want it ?

Comment: read edit delete read edit delete in the same row, with ng-repeat

Comment: @Sajeetharan http://i.imgur.com/KojxxdW.jpg

Comment: <tr><tr ng-repeat="rol in aRoles"> remove this unnecessary <tr> tag before rol in aRoles.

Comment: Can you add working fiddler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below `ng-repeat`

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
$scope.aRoles=
     [
       {
         "type_content": "articles", 
         "type_usuario":{
          "administrator":
           {"write":true, "read":true, "delete":true},
          "other":
           {"write":true, "read":true, "delete":true}
         }     
       },
       {
         "type_content": "papers", 
         "type_usuario":{
          "administrator":
           {"write":true, "read":true, "delete":true},
          "other":
           {"write":true, "read":true, "delete":true}
         }     
       },
     ]        
    $scope.atypeUsers=Object.keys($scope.aRoles[0].type_usuario);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
      
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
   <table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Type of content</th>
        <th colspan="{{atypeUsers.length * 3}}">
     Type of users
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td ng-repeat="usu in atypeUsers" colspan="3">
        {{usu}}
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat-start="usu in atypeUsers">READ</td>
        <td >EDIT</td>
        <td ng-repeat-end>DELETE</td>
        -------------------
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="rol in aRoles">
       <td>{{rol.type_content}}</td>
       <td >true</td>
       <td >false</td>
       <td >true</td>
       <td >false</td>
       <td >true</td>
       <td >false</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use [`ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points)

```
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3">Type of content</th>
    <th colspan="{{atypeUsers.length * 3}}">
      Type of users
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td ng-repeat="usu in atypeUsers" colspan="3">
    {{usu}}
   </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td ng-repeat-start="usu in atypeUsers">
    READ
   </td>
   <td>
    EDIT
   </td>
   <td ng-repeat-end>
    DELETE
   </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: @yavg - Why downvote and what is not working? this should work - check this fiddle out - https://jsfiddle.net/2opv2ryo/2/

Comment: this is a better approach! :)

Comment: @Developer excuse me! Create your answer again, and I will qualify you. In your previous answer had not worked.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can define another function which reads your json and creates an array which populates the rights and you can simply use it in the `<td>` with ngRepeat in the code.

I've achieved what you wanted with this approach, though my code is little messy, you can refine it to your needs.

check this  [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uMhr8zoUpfEuiqymTySC?p=preview)